# Apache - How to compress (gzip) only specific calls

Tags: apache-2.2, php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-deflate

I have PHP application served with Apache 2.4
I need the apache to compress (mod_deflate - gzip) calls for specific users. So the application should decides dynamically which calls gets gzipped.
I was thinking of adding custom header. something like 'gzip-this-call:true'

How do I set htaccess to make only calls with this header get compressed?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you want to solve this in Apache, and not in your PHP application? Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043284/how-to-get-send-gzip-content-as-php-response